# LDAP Server_Down Error

Tags: python, ldap

I'm trying to set up ldap with Python.  When I run `./manage.py syncldap` I get:

> ```
> SERVER_DOWN: {'info': 'TLS: hostname does not match CN in peer certificate', 
> 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}
> ```

Other people working on the same codebase on their local machines don't seem to be having any problem.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the CN from Subject of server cert

   ```
   openssl x509 -noout -text -in imsva_cert.pem | grep Subject
   Subject: C=en, ST=xx, O=yy, OU=zz, CN=test.com
   ```
2. The "hostname" in the error is to say the host name in your command to access LDAP server, so please just use host test.com, e.g.

   ```
   ldapsearch -H "ldaps://test.com:636" ...
   ```
3. Also don't forget add test.com in your DNS server to make sure ldapsearch can get the A record for host test.com. Specify the info in /etc/hosts is a easy way.

Answer (score 1):

Your other folk, using the same codebase on their local machines, are they talking to the same LDAP server?  The SSL certificate used to enable LDAP over SSL/TLS will have a name embedded in it.  (Not editable, you would need to reissue a new cert with a new CN)

The message is saying the Hostname of the server is not the same as the hostname in the certificate (This is why Wildcard certs are so darn useful.  No need for a new cert for every box, just use the wildcard and keep the domain the same).

I would examine the certificate, in whatever keystore it is held in, on the server side, and look at the hostname to see the differences..

Comment: I'm afraid a lot of this is over my head--I've never done anything with certs or whatnot.  If you could elaborate, or point me in the direction of documentation, I'd greatly appreciate it.